# Can a damaged CV joint cause clunking noise?

Tags: noise, suspension, cv-joint, ball-joint

It was raining the other day and my tires do not have a lot of tread on them. I was taking this on ramp on too high of speed than I should have and ended up oversteering off the pavement into grass with the wheels at full lock to the right.

Luckily there does not seem to be much damage done to my car except when I drive on bumpy roads I hear a clunking noise from the right side of my vehicle.

I jacked up the car and checked for any obvious damage in the suspension parts and I could not find any. The ball joint seemed to be fine too with no signs of wear. When I tried to move the CV with my hands in and out I was able to move it slightly and it seemed to make a similar type of noise to what I am hearing. So does this mean I would have to replace my CV joint? The noise just does not make sense to be coming from the CV joint as I have never heard of a CV joint making this type of noise, or can it?

The vehicle is an 05 Civic HX for reference.

Comment: Bumpy roads is more likely a damaged or broken swaybar link.  The damage might not be visible.  More likely a suspension issue as a result of the "off-roading" than CV damage.  A bad CV will make a regular click-click-click, but usually only while turning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the strut top bolt got loose from the accident and as the car was going over bumps it would hit the mount and make the clunking noise.